# VBA Error Code Object Required --- Have Triple checked but still not working

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

The commented lines below continue to return to me the error `Run Time Error'424': Object Required`. I am working on this as part of a self learn class, and I have tripled checked to make sure I am entering the code properly and am still returning this error. I tried looking at other examples of this error on here, but none were helpful to this instance because I do not know the code well enough yet.

Thank you!

```
Sub FirstArray()

Dim Fruit(2) As String

Fruit(0) = "Apple"
Fruit(1) = "Banana"
Fruit(2) = "Cherry"
Range("A1").Text = "First Fruit: " & Fruit(1)
' ^ RUN TIME ERROR 424

Dim Veg(1 To 3) As String

Veg(1) = "Artichoke"
Veg(2) = "Broccoli"
Veg(3) = "Cabbage"
Range("B1").Text = "First Veg:" & Veg(1)
' ^ RUN TIME ERROR 424

Dim Flower() As String
ReDim Flower(1 To 3)

Flower(1) = "Azalea"
Flower(2) = "Buttercup"
Flower(3) = "Crocus"
Range("C1").Text = "Final Flower:" & Flower(3)
' ^ RUN TIME ERROR 424





End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, the lines with the ***....***. I did not realize that the code would not allow me to post it as bold or italicized on here....

Comment: `.Text` is a read only property.  You want `.Value`

Comment: You can add comments (--) to the part of the code you want us to look at

Comment: @kazzi `--` is for commenting SQL; VBA code is commented using a single quote `'` or the [obsolete] `Rem` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change `.Text` to `.Value`

Comment: Alternatively, just *drop* the `.Text` and let the assignment be made on the `Range` object's *default member*, which happens to point to... its `Value`. (I personally prefer explicitly referring to `.Value` though)

Answer (score 3):

[Changing .Text for .Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46717437/1188513) will fix it, but in case you're wondering how "Object required" even remotely makes sense as an error message, here's why.

You know the syntax for *implicit value assignment*:

```
foo.Bar = 42
```

The *explicit value assignment* syntax is still supported, but obsolete/deprecated:

```
Let foo.Bar = 42
```

This assignment calls the `Property Let` accessor of the `Bar` property of the `foo` object, which could look something like this:

```
Public Property Let Bar(ByVal value As Long)
    internalBar = value
End Property

Public Property Get Bar() as Long
    Bar = internalBar
End Property
```

In the case of `Range.Text`, the property might look something like this:

```
Public Property Get Text() As String
    Text = GetStringRepresentationOfValue
End Property
```

Notice there's no `Property Let` accessor, so this:

```
someRange.Text = "foo"
```

Isn't legal, because the `Text` property doesn't expose a `Property Let` accessor.

So what's the deal with *object required*? Getting to it.

But first you need to know what a *default member* is. You see every class module *can* define a "default member". For collections that member is usually the `Item` property, by convention.

This means whether you do this:

```
foo = myCollection.Item(12)
```

Or that:

```
foo = myCollection(12)
```

You get the exact same `foo`, exactly the same way - the two are *exactly the same*.. except the latter *implicitly* calls the *default member*, and the former *explicitly* does so.

> A class' *default member* is determined by a hidden member attribute
>   that you can only see if you export the class module and open it in a
>   text editor:
>
> ```
> Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Long) As Variant
> Attribute Foo.VB_UserMemId = 0
>     Item = internalCollection(Index)
> End Property
> ```
>
> Only 1 member in a class can be the default.

So what the error message is saying, is that when it sees this:

```
foo.Bar = 42
```

And knows that `Bar` is a read-only property that only exposes a `Property Get` accessor, then the only way for this code to be legal, is if `Bar` returns an object that has a default member that can be assigned to take that value.

And since `Range.Text` returns a `String` and not an `Object`, VBA complains that *an object is required*.

Comment: I answered the question and this was still very helpful to me. So thanks for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
Range("B1") = "First Veg:" & Veg(1)
```

Same for

```
Range("C1") = "Final Flower:" & Flower(3)
```