# Countifs object not found error 424

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, countif

I'm new here and new to vba. I was tryng to do a countif and if answer is over 0 than the criteria is respected, therefore I have double cheque issued problem on more than 500 rows.

```
Sub DoubleCheck() 
'Variables declaration
Dim row_rounter As Long, rngQ As Range, cel As Range, resDblChq As Variant,    rngB As Range, rngC As Range, rngF As Range, rngH As Range, rngI As Range
row_counter = Sheets("GW-DB").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'row counter

'Range Initializatoin

 Set rngQ = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("Q2:Q" & row_counter)
 Set rngC = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("C2:C" & row_counter)
Set rngF = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("F2:F" & row_counter)
Set rngH = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("H2:H" & row_counter)
Set rngI = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("I2:I" & row_counter)
Set rngB = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("B2:B" & row_counter)
'Loop starts to validate possibility of double cheques

For Each cel In rngQ
' countif same name, same date,same amount, same reason
resDblChq = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngB, c.Offset(0, -16).Value, rngC, c.Offset(0, -15).Value, rngF, c.Offset(0, -12).Value, rngH, c.Offset(0, -9).Value, rngI, c.Offset(0, -8).Value)

' if it counts more than 0 it means there's a possibility of having double cheques issued
If resDblChq > 0 Then
c.Value = "Possible payment made twice"
End If
Next cel



End Sub
```

Thank You and I want to keep the most simple way for  further modification

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error is Error 424 object required

Comment: What line does it throw the error on?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46717863/1188513) to understand *why* you're getting that specific error, and note that specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of the module would have prevented that error.

Comment: Thank you for all your aswner this was truly because of the reference c.

Comment: one more question: i use countif but it return 0. I looked up and they say for countifs, arg1 is the range and arg2 to ... are the criteria. However, how can I put more than one range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loops you are referencing `C` instead of `Cel`.  Try changing that like this.  This will generate the error 424.

```
Sub DoubleCheck() 
'Variables declaration
Dim row_rounter As Long, rngQ As Range, cel As Range, resDblChq As Variant,    rngB As Range, rngC As Range, rngF As Range, rngH As Range, rngI As Range
row_counter = Sheets("GW-DB").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'row counter

'Range Initializatoin

 Set rngQ = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("Q2:Q" & row_counter)
 Set rngC = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("C2:C" & row_counter)
Set rngF = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("F2:F" & row_counter)
Set rngH = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("H2:H" & row_counter)
Set rngI = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("I2:I" & row_counter)
Set rngB = Sheets("GW-DB").Range("B2:B" & row_counter)
'Loop starts to validate possibility of double cheques

For Each cel In rngQ
' countif same name, same date,same amount, same reason
resDblChq = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngB, cel.Offset(0, -16).Value, rngC, cel.Offset(0, -15).Value, rngF, cel.Offset(0, -12).Value, rngH, cel.Offset(0, -9).Value, rngI, cel.Offset(0, -8).Value)

' if it counts more than 0 it means there's a possibility of having double cheques issued
If resDblChq > 0 Then
cel.Value = "Possible payment made twice"
End If
Next cel



End Sub
```

Comment: And again one of those errors that can easily be avoided using `option explicit`...

Comment: oops... i saw Jarom's answer now... i guess i tool too long to check for answer...

Answer (score 1):

use cel instead of c

```
 resDblChq = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngB, cel.Offset(0, -16).Value, rngC, cel.Offset(0, -15).Value, rngF, cel.Offset(0, -12).Value, rngH, cel.Offset(0, -9).Value, rngI, cel.Offset(0, -8).Value)
```

Comment: The first problem is now fixed but do you know why the function return 0? The ranges are exact. Can I only put one range? Thanks

Comment: yes, you can try one argument and check. before checking, i suggest to trim the strings in data since you are using a string function and spaces may easily be overlooked upon or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is undeclared, and because `Option Explicit` isn't specified, at run-time it's therefore an implicit `Variant` that contains `vbEmpty`:

```
    Debug.Assert Not IsEmpty(c) ' assertion fails here
    Debug.Print c.Offset(0, -16).Value '"object required"
```

Sure you can [use `Cel` instead of `c`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832545/1188513), but that won't prevent the myriad of other annoyingly **easy-to-avoid** run-time errors that merely specifying `Option Explicit` at the top of every single module would.

VBA will happily compile typos and declare them as on-the-fly implicit `Variant` variables without `Option Explicit` specified: this is NOT how you write reliable code. Use. Option. Explicit.

The reason why the error says "object required", is because syntactically, `c.Offset(0, -16).Value` can only ever be a `Property Get` or `Function` member call on an object named `c` - however `IsObject(c)` would be `False`, because `vbEmpty` isn't an object reference. Hence, *object required*.